# visual studio Cordova send mail using smtp or any other kinda method

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

hello guys i'm using Cordova  in visual studio and i wanna send an email similar to phpmailer. but i wanna do it with Cordova i tried many ways to do it i even found a plugin called

cordova-smtp-client  i install it and it gives me an Error when i try to run  the application on android

js code

```
document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", function () {

    alert("yes we did it ")
    var mailSettings = {
        emailFrom: "emailFrom@domain.com",
        emailTo: "emailTo@domain.com",
        smtp: "smtp-mail.domain.com",
        smtpUserName: "authuser@domain.com",
        smtpPassword: "password",
        attachments: ["attchament1", "attchament2"],
        subject: "email subject",
        textBody: "write something within the boddy of the email"
    };

    var success = function (message) {
        alert(message);
    }

    var failure = function (message) {
        alert("Error sending the email");
    }

    smtpClient.sendMail(mailSettings, success, failure);

});
```

error image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccwEQ.png)

please if there any other way to send secure email using cordova in visual studio  could you share it with me. thank you

Comment: 1. I don't think you can use Cordova, i.e. JavaScript to send email, even if you can, the password is 'readable' to all users running the app.

Comment: The proper way should be something like using ajax to 'call' a php program in the server side, then use php to send the email